# match criteria and repeat value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rows, repeat

I'm trying to create a dynamic formula to match the `Location` and `start_time` and copy the `value` based on the `replicate` count.

I'm able to index/match `location` and `start_time` to get the `value` but unable to include a dynamic formula to have the `value` `replicate`

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Ideal Outcome:**

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: can you show what formula you got?

Answer (score 1):

So you already know where the first value should go, so I'll leave that to you.

To fill the voids in between you could use a formula like this:

```
=IF(ROW()-1="";"";IF(ROW()<=ROW($F$2)+INDEX($A$2:$D$7;MATCH($F$1;$A$2:$A$7);4)-1;INDEX($A$2:$D$7;MATCH($F$1;$A$2:$A$7);3);0))
```

Here I assumed that your Sample data is in A1 to D7 and your ideal outcome starts in E1 and that you filled `0.12` in cell F2. The formula is then entered in F3 and dragged down. The only thing that you would now need to adapt is to replace the absolute reference to F2 with your formula to find the cell values were to insert the first data.

The first part of the formula:

```
=IF(ROW()-1="";"";
```

checks if the cell directly above the cell the formula is in is blank. If so a blank is returned, otherwise the rest of the formula is executed.

The second IF statement:

```
IF(ROW()<=ROW($F$2)+INDEX($A$2:$D$7;MATCH($F$1;$A$2:$A$7);4)-1;
```

checks if the current row number is less then or equal to the first row number where your value occured (Cell F2) plus the amount of repetitions minus 1 (as there is already one value in F2)

The last part of the formula:

```
INDEX($A$2:$D$7;MATCH($F$1;$A$2:$A$7);3);0))
```

then fills in the appropriate value using `INDEX(MATCH())` against your input data.

Comment: hey @luuklag, i've been tinkering with the suggestion you provided. Its helped a lot but struggling with a couple things: . 
- dynamically identifying where the first value should go as that changes  - handle when some `locations`have multiple `start_time`. For example, Los Angeles has 2 `start_time` . 

I appreciate your assistance with this

Comment: You should first match the start time, using index match, and then find the apropiate column, using index match again. This way you can find multiple start times for the same location.